# Bit masking (javascript): how to check ALL flags

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, masking, bitmask

If I have the number '00001000' and the mask '00101000', how can i check, with a binary operation, if both the bits in the number are set? `number & mask` return true if at least one bit match, but I need to check for all of them to match.
How to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just compare to the mask:

```
if ((number & mask) === mask) {
  // all bits are set!
}
```

The only way the result of the `&` operation will be exactly the same as the value of the mask is when the number has all the bits set. (The test number may have *more* bits set; if you want to check to see if it's got exactly the same bits set and unset, then that's a simple equality test.)

Comment: I guess you have to put parenthesis around `(number & mask)`  otherwise the equality test is performed in the first place

Comment: Other ways include `(flags | mask) == flags`, or `((~flags) & mask) == 0)`.  But yeah `(flags & mask) == mask` is the standard idiom. https://godbolt.org/z/8P79sz4h3 shows how C compilers handle it, with clang transforming to `((~flags) & mask) == 0)` on some ISAs where that's more efficient. AArch64 allows a different encoding for immediates to bitwise boolean instructions, allowing repeated bit-patterns.  In Javascript this is all up to the JIT, but same difference.